# Reference to same class as type of function argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

It seems like in Python 3, I can't let a class reference to itself:

```
class A:
    def test(self, param: A):
            print('Hello World')
```

Python gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in A
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

I can I make this code work?

Comment: Is that supposed to be an equal sign after `param`?

Comment: @James, no, it is supposed to be a type hint: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: ```def test(self, param: 'A'):```  solved the problem.